# ODBC Driver error

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, odbc, connection-string

I am getting following error in my website:

> "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
>   /cgi-bin/bins/search_djsNewLayout.asp, line 717"

I accessed the file by going to `/cgi-bin/bins/search_djsNewLayout.asp` and, on line 717, I got this:

```
Cnxn.Open "DRIVER=" & DBDRIVER & ";DBQ=" & Server.Mappath(DBDSN) & ";", adModeReadWrite"
```

I don't know what the error is in this as I am new to Classic ASP. Please help me out I am attaching the whole file as well which needs to be edited. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Did it ever work? Did you change something? Is there a database file at the location `Server.Mappath(DBDSN)`? Probably the value of DBDSN is not correct.

Comment: I didnt changed anything my website is showing error on line 717 same file.  you can check the website here for error  http://www.1800djsareus.com/cgi-bin/bins/search_djsNewLayout.asp do you tihnk i have to make a change of the name in anything as i cant understand what to change it to.. :(

Comment: As stated by John, you need to identify the value of `DBDSN`, and see if either the DSN exists, or the Access database that it's trying to attach to. PS: Positing and unverified link like that is bad form.

Comment: I want to know where this DBSN is located? so i can check on it if it is there or not

Answer (score 0):

1. Okay, to track the variable you need to load the file into an editor, e.g. Notepad, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> `DBDSN`.
2. If it's not in there, then you need to look for `include` files, usually (but not always) at the top of the file you're editing.  Look for any lines with `<!-- #include file="..." -->` in them, and check the filename associated to see if the variable is located in that.
3. If you still do not find the variable, chances are it is located in a `global.asa` file. Check the file's folder and its parent folder for the `global.asa` file.

Comment: ok I SEARCH FOR INCLUDE AND FOUND THE FILE AND WENT IN IT AND HERE IS WHAT I GOT IN INCLUDE FILE. I THINK WE ARE NEAR TO FIX IT :)
<% Option Explicit %>


<%
Const DBDSN = "\db\DJS_Da2.mdb"
Const DBDRIVER = "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}"
Const DBUID = "mskorusa"
Const DBPWD = "991370"

%>

Comment: and now i am getting error on line 729 the previous error went away.

Comment: @UsmanAbbasi: You may find that your folder needs the appropriate windows account access for IIS; a basic access rights issue.  Personally I would have put it in a data folder under *wwwroot*. Please delete your first comment as it has username and password details in it.

Comment: thanks for telling me sir hope so i will get it fixed soon :)